# Angular Environment congiagration Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Error: src/app/components/rooms/add-room/services/room.service.ts:40:51 - error TS2339: Property 'apiBaseUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.

40     return this.http.delete(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/Rooms/${id}`);
~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVoLC.png)

how to solve this error i am using angular 16

Comment: what is a *congiagration issue*

Comment: Please don't use screenshots but write out the contents of `environment.ts` and also 
 `room.service.ts` where you import and use the environment configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apiBaseUrl variable is defined in each src/environments/ directory.
Exemple :

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://my-url'
};
```

environment.development.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://my-url'
};
```

To use the environment configurations you have defined, your service must import the original environments file:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';


this.http.delete(‘${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/Rooms/${id}’);
```